# Assign polygon duplicate area (overlap) to only one polygon

Tags: r, overlap, polygons

I have a shapefile (which can be downloaded here http://www.car.gov.br/publico/municipios/downloads?sigla=MA (any would do)) where each polygon represent a rural private property, as the owner submited it. However, the polygons overlap. For the analysis I need to run, an area cannot be accounted twice (ie. be in two properties ). So, on the areas that do overlap, I wanted to assign this duplicate area to the polygon with the smallest area and erase it from the other one.

I've looked at other questions such as [**this one**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52817/remove-intersect-of-one-polygon-from-another-in-r). But none do really adress this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by subtracting the smaller polygon from the larger using `rgeos::gDifference`.

An example:

First we make some dummy polygons to demonstrate on

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
p1 <- Polygon(matrix(c(
  100, 100,
  100, 500,
  900, 500,
  900, 100,
  100, 100), ncol=2, byrow = T))
p2 <- Polygon(matrix(c(
  50, 400,
  50, 600,
  800, 600,
  800, 400,
  50, 400), ncol=2, byrow = T))
p1 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(p1), "p1")))
p2 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(p2), "p2")))
plot(p1)
plot(p2, add=T)
```

[image]

We can use `gArea` to find which is smaller

```
a1 = gArea(p1)
## [1] 320000
a2 = gArea(p2)
## [1] 150000
```

Now we can remove the intersection from the larger polygon with like this:

```
if (a1>a2){
  p3 = gDifference(p1,p2)
  p4 = p2
} else {
  p3 = gDifference(p2,p1)
  p4 = p1
}
plot(p3)
```

[image]

The two polygons together look like this

```
plot(p4, add=T)
```

[image]